# Opencv3.0.0 beta , building from source do not include ml package And The dlls sizes are different

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I used cmake to build opencv 3 sources in Visual studio 10. In the Release folder i get all dlls and this includes opencv_ml300.dll and opencv_java300.dll too. But the opencv-300.jar do not contain the ml classes. Can any one point me in the right path?

Also the opencv_java300.dll that comes with the opencv 3.3.3 installation  in windows is 20mb and the one i built is only 583 kb. what might be wrong?

Comment: Hi! I am successfully build the OpenCV with extra modules and created the Jar file for Java, which I tested it was working well, but I did not see any new things in this Jar file, I mean that where the contrib code for Java, this Jar file is almost the same as the Jar file which came whit OpenCV download file. If you understand me the question, please tell me that I did wrong some where in building Jar file Or it is like this? Thank you very much. Note: I have included everything while build Jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ml module got a major overhaul in 3.0, so java/python/matlab wrappers are temporarily disabled for that.

no idea, what to do. wait till they fix it ? make an [issue](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues) ? fall back to 2.4 in the meantime ?

the prebuild java dll is linked statically(does not need further opencv dlls), while the one you build is probably dynamic(depends on the opencv dlls on the PATH). so, nothing wrong with the size.

if you want to build static libs, that's :

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

Comment: ok i will fall back to 2.4. thanks, also how to build it statically?

Comment: Hi! I am successfully build the OpenCV with extra modules and created the Jar file for Java, which I tested it was working well, but I did not see any new things in this Jar file, I mean that where the contrib code for Java, this Jar file is almost the same as the Jar file which came whit OpenCV download file. If you understand me the question, please tell me that I did wrong some where in building Jar file Or it is like this? Thank you very much. Note: I have included everything while build Jar file

Comment: afaik, the bioinspired module is the only one from contrib, that actually has java wrappers (atm)

Comment: Only bioinspired? yes I saw this package, but it is very little things, in the contrib I saw so many things like `Scene Text Detection and Recognition`,  `Deep Neural Network module`, `Extended Image Processing` and so on, but how to use now?